# Using cv2.calibratecamera for point correspondences on not a single plane (non-planar calibration rigs)

Tags: python, opencv

I'm learning about different ways to use cv2.calibrateCamera and ran into this issue.

For one image I have N point correspondences. These N points belong to 2 perpendicular planes. Imagine two chess boards perpendicular to one another.

When I pass points from a single plane to cv2.calibrateCamera I get acceptible results but I wanted to utilize more points. I was tryin to pass points belonging to two different planes as separate images.

So my `objectPoints = [points_on_plane1, points_on_plane2]`
However I still get this error:

```
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.5) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\calib3d\src\calibration.cpp:1576: error: (-5:Bad argument) For non-planar calibration rigs the initial intrinsic matrix must be specified in function 'cvCalibrateCamera2Internal'
```

What is the correct way to use points from two different planes?

---------- Update ------

I tried first getting the calibration matrix from one plane and than passing it as an input to claibrateCamera with set of two points. No error message, however as an ouput I get two separate `rvecs` and `tvecs` which is not what I wanted.

I would like to get fix `rcecs` abd `tvecs` as they are supposed to be the same. Should I pass all points from both planes together on the second pass?

Comment: all it says is that you should guess an intrinsic matrix and pass it. it can't start from nothing. it can be a bad guess but there needs to be one. -- an "image" is all the points from an *image*. don't separate your rig's walls into "different images". I mean, you could, but then you artificially made your rig planar.